# Woocommerce allow access only products

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, endpoint, woocommerce-rest-api

I have enabled REST API so 3RD party can read store products.

But by giving API Access they can also access all other information for example Customer details, orders, reports and so on.

I wrote the following function to allow access to only to product via API

```
function restrict_woocommerce_rest_api_endpoints() {


$allowed_endpoints = array(
    '/wp-json/wc/v3/products?consumer_key=cs_key&consumer_secret=cs_secret',
  );

$current_endpoint = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
$allowed = in_array($current_endpoint, $allowed_endpoints);

if (!$allowed) {
    // If the requested endpoint is not in the allowed list, return a 403 Forbidden status.
    status_header(403);
    //echo  $current_endpoint ;
    echo "Access Forbidden";
    exit;
}
}
add_action('rest_api_init', 'restrict_woocommerce_rest_api_endpoints');
```

But this function is blocking access woocommerce Admin dashboard as i can see a blank page with Access Forbidden msg.

Thank You

Comment: You follow this Url. Hope your problem will be solved. https://woocommerce.github.io/woocommerce-rest-api-docs/wp-api-v2.html?php#introduction